# implode() glue not working PHP

Tags: php

The expected behaviour of the code is

> dynamically assign value to array (this is done a few times) and then print it

Code:

```
$PLLinks = array();

$sql245 = "SELECT `Username`, `Password`, `MacAddress` FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` LIKE '$guestUsername' AND `Password` LIKE '$guestPassword' AND `MacAddress` LIKE '$guestMacAddress'";
$result4 = mysql_query($sql245);
if (mysql_num_rows($result4) == 1) {


for ($i = 0; $i<count($Checknames); $i++)
{   

    if ($PLNames[$i] == 'Valid' && $PLChecked[$i] == 'Invalid'){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `Link` FROM `Checksums` WHERE `Name`       LIKE '$ValidNames[$i]' LIMIT 1");

    $value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $PLChecked[] = $value->{'Link'};
    echo $value->{'Link'};


    }
    else if ($PLNames[$i] == 'Valid' && $PLChecked[$i] != 'Invalid') {

        $PLLinks[] = 'noUpd';
    }
    else if ($PLNames[$i] != 'Valid') {

        $PLLinks[] = 'Remove';
    }
}


echo implode(',', $PLLinks); 
    // this should print "a,b,c" but instead it prints "abc"
}
```

If the solution is simple, please **hint it only**.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please show the **actual** code your using.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone added.

Comment: What do you see if you do a `var_dump($PLLinks)`? It works fine for me. `echo implode(',', array('a', 'b', 'c'));` outputs 'a,b,c'

Comment: var_dump() your $PLLinks before the implode.... see exactly what elements the array contains

Comment: var_dump worked. I added the right value to the wrong array , and for some seemingly magical reason I echoed that value (so it actually displayed) and later I imploded the array. So what was displaying is (echo + implode's echo)